# Linq To SQL Query for counting same records

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7

I have a working code to check input with database & if the same record is found it's shown that no other same record can be made

but i want to change it a little bit by counting the same number of records & show the count in a `TextBox`

```
var a = from b in ContactDB.GetTable<ContactInfo>() select b;
foreach (var x in a)
{
    if (x.Extra == txtname.Text.ToString())
    {
         // code
    }
}
```

How to count the total `x.Extra` found same as `thxname.Text` & show the count in info.TextBox

Comment: Do you want the records count by matching Extra field with input data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
infoTextBox.Text = a.Count(x => x.Extra == txtname.Text).ToString();
```